# Tab bar icons are too big in interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, interface-builder

The tab bar icons are too big in Xcode interface builder. They are correctly sized when running on a device however. This is how it looks in IB:

[image: interface-builder]

According to Apple's [design guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/) we should:

> **Prepare glyphs with a scale factor of @2x and save them as PDFs.** Because PDF is a vector format that allows for high-resolution scaling, it's typically sufficient to provide a single @2x version in your app and allow it to scale for other resolutions.

So I'm using PDFs of size 46x46 px and named them `filename@2x.pdf`:
[image: assets]

Is it a bug in Xcode or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Icons are big because the icons are big, man, make @1x (23x23) for these icon files and it will look nice on your storyboard.

Comment: Hint: upload PDF files of size 25px x 25px. That will make sure the icons always look sharp and it will also fix your storyboard issue.

Comment: This fixed it! Linus & @rptwsthi

Answer (score 0):

It is showing too big because, you have selected the small device type for IB and you didn't add all variations of icons in assets.
You can change IB device type on tapping "View As:" (Refer image) 
or you can add all 1x, 2x and 3x images on assets file.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't do it; tried with all the different iPhone variations. Also tried adding a 25x25 1x image, but the bigger one overrides. Seems like the solution is to *only* have a 25x25 1x and remove the 2x one, as rptwsthi and @LinusGeffarth suggested in the comments.